# Getting tweets via TWRequest for a tableview

Tags: uitableview, tableview, twrequest

Ok, I'm pretty new to this and been struggling with what you guys may feel is quite an easy exercise. I have trawled high and low and cannot find a good tutorial or walkthrough on how to do this. Basically, I am using the code below to obtain tweets and I only want the 'text' part of the tweet. How do I extract it out of the NSDictionary in order to use the 'text' key in a tableview? I have tried `[dict objectForKey:@"text"]` but it does not work - 'dict' does not seem to contain a 'text' attribute. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
// Do a simple search, using the Twitter API
TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
   @"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=iOS%205&rpp=5&with_twitter_user_id=true&result_type=recent"] 
   parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

// Notice this is a block, it is the handler to process the response
[request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
{
  if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200) 
  {
    // The response from Twitter is in JSON format
    // Move the response into a dictionary and print
    NSError *error;        
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Twitter response: %@", dict);                           
  }
  else
    NSLog(@"Twitter error, HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]);
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is an objectForKey@"text" but it is an array which means that every entry (tweet) has text (and several other attributes). So we've to loop through the tweets to get FOR every tweet the text.

In your .h file

```
         NSMutableArray *twitterText;
```

In your .m file

Do this somewhere in viewdidload

```
         twitterText = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

And now we can loop through your results. Paste this code where you've NSLog(@"Twitter response: %@", dict);

```
          NSArray *results = [dict objectForKey@"results"];

         //Loop through the results

         for (NSDictionary *tweet in results)
         {
             // Get the tweet
             NSString *twittext = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];

             // Save the tweet to the twitterText array
             [twitterText addObject:(twittext)];
```

And for your cells in your tableView

```
         cell.textLabel.text = [twitterText objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I think that should be working.

Comment: Thanks. I've followed your instructions but still no joy. the line NSArray *results = [dict objectForKey@"results"]; flags up error "Expected]" the line 'else' flags up "Expected expression" and the closing '}];' flags up "Expected expression". I am putting the loop through code directly after the log line that you mentioned, so just before the } before 'else' is that correct? What have I done wrong?

Comment: Sorry mate! forgot :
          NSArray *results = [dict objectForKey:@"results"]; and I forgot to close the for (NSDictionary *tweet in results) so you've to add a } at the end of that part

Comment: Hi thanks for your help however - I'm getting a SIGABRT due to my twitterText array being empty? Why would that be? There is a texy component there but it is not extracting it for some reason

Comment: sorry forgot to add the debugger message.... *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack: